# Calculated values from data returned by Ransack are removed when paginating with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari, ransack

On my Rails application, I am performing calculations on the data returned by Ransack. These are:

- Total count
- Averages on certain fields

The averages work but as soon as I go to the next page (using Kaminari pagination) the values disappear. However, total count continues to work.

From the view, this works:

```
<%= @products.total_count %>
```

Also from the view, this works, but when going to the next page, it doesn't:

```
<%= number_to_percentage(@products.average(:status), precision: 0) %>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Products controller:

```
def index
    @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = 'start_date desc' if @q.sorts.empty?
    @products = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

This is the SQL query from when it works on the first page:

```
(23.7ms)  SELECT  AVG("products"."price_eur") AS avg_id FROM "products"  WHERE (status > 100) AND "products"."above_revenue_average" = 't' AND ("products"."name" ILIKE '%a%') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

And the params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"a", "type_eq"=>"", "upward_trending"=>"1", "downward_trending"=>"", "category_id_in"=>[""], "country_eq"=>"", "price_eur_gteq"=>"", "price_eur_lteq"=>"", "start_date_gteq"=>"", "start_date_lteq"=>""}, "commit"=>"All"}
```

This is the SQL query from when it stops working on the second page:

```
(23.8ms)  SELECT  AVG("products"."price_eur") AS avg_id FROM "products"  WHERE (status > 100) AND "products"."above_revenue_average" = 't' AND ("products"."name" ILIKE '%a%')
```

And the params:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"All", "page"=>"2", "q"=>{"category_id_in"=>[""], "country_eq"=>"", "downward_trending"=>"", "name_cont"=>"a", "price_eur_gteq"=>"", "price_eur_lteq"=>"", "start_date_gteq"=>"", "start_date_lteq"=>"", "type_eq"=>"", "upward_trending"=>"1"}, "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be quite an easy fix, just need to run the calculations on @q.result

```
<%= number_to_percentage(@q.result.average(:status), precision: 0) %>
```